# Пересоздается ListView android

Tags: android, listview, java

В первой функции создаю **Листвью**:

```
    public void getWall(){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

       url = "https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/wall.get?owner_id=-34215577&count=10";

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            responses = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);

           for(int i = 1; i < responses.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = responses.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                Integer time = c.getInt(TAG_DATE);
                String text = c.getString(TAG_TEXT);
                String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date(time*1000));
                JSONObject likes = c.getJSONObject(TAG_LIKES);
                JSONObject reposts = c.getJSONObject(TAG_REPOSTS);

                //Count Likes
                String likes_count = likes.getString(TAG_COUNT);
                String reposts_count = reposts.getString(TAG_COUNT);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_ID, "ПОСТ #"+id);
                map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                map.put(TAG_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(text).toString());
                map.put("likes_count", likes_count);
                map.put("reposts_count", reposts_count);
                contactList.add(map);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ***ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.item_list,
                new String[] { TAG_ID,TAG_TEXT,TAG_DATE,  "reposts_count", "likes_count" }, new int[] {R.id.id_item,
                        R.id.item_text, R.id.item_time, R.id.item_reposts,R.id.item_likes });***

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Потом мне нужно добавить новый элемент:

```
    public void getNewItemWall(int paged){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        url = "https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/wall.get?owner_id=-34215577&count=3&offset="+paged;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            responses = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);

           for(int i = 1; i < responses.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = responses.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                Integer time = c.getInt(TAG_DATE);
                String text = c.getString(TAG_TEXT);
                String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date(time*1000));
                JSONObject likes = c.getJSONObject(TAG_LIKES);
                JSONObject reposts = c.getJSONObject(TAG_REPOSTS);

                //Count Likes
                String likes_count = likes.getString(TAG_COUNT);
                String reposts_count = reposts.getString(TAG_COUNT);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                map.put(TAG_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(text).toString());
                map.put("likes_count", likes_count);
                map.put("reposts_count", reposts_count);
                contactList.add(map);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.item_list,
                new String[] { TAG_TEXT,TAG_DATE,  "reposts_count", "likes_count" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.item_text, R.id.item_time, R.id.item_reposts,R.id.item_likes });

        lv = mContainerView.getList();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Но при парсинге нового элемента пересоздается листвью и там всего 1 элемент

Comment: ну, естественно.    
Вы же во второй функции создаете новый список элементов    
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();       

Добавляете в него 1 элемент    
И создаете на его базе новый адаптер( в итоге с 1 элементом), и выставляете адаптер в листВью

Answer (score 2):

Во втором методе вместо создания нового списка и адаптера Вам нужно получить ссылки на уже существующие и добавлять/обновлять данные в них